# the text won't blit into the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to blit the score in the left corner of the screen. I have currently been trying for 2 hours and nothing seems to be working.

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 72)     
text = "Score:" + str(enemies_clicked)
label = font.render(text, 1, red)
screen.blit(label, (20, 10))
```

There are no error messages. I tried different fonts and everything seems to work, except the text.
The font variable is declared between the `pygame.init()` and the while loop. The other 3 lines are 2 indents deep in the while loop.

Complete code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
from random import randint as random

pygame.init()

width = 600
height = 400

block_size = 40

enemy_size = block_size
enemy_pos = [int(random(1,14)*block_size), int(random(1,8)*block_size)]
enemies_clicked = 0

font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 72)

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("click game")

def clicked_on_enemy(enemy_pos, enemy_size, click_pos):

    e_x = enemy_pos[0]
    e_y = enemy_pos[1]
    c_e = click_pos[0]
    c_y = click_pos[1]

    x_col = False
    y_col = False

    for i in range(enemy_size):
        if e_x + i == c_e:
            x_col = True

    for i in range(enemy_size):
        if e_y + i == c_y:
            y_col = True

    if x_col and y_col:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#main loop#
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            click_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if clicked_on_enemy(enemy_pos, enemy_size, click_pos):
                enemy_pos = [int(random(1,14) * block_size), int(random(1,8) * block_size)]
                enemies_clicked += 1

        text = "Score:" + str(enemies_clicked)  
        label = font.render(text, 1, red)
        screen.blit(label, (20, 10))

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (enemy_pos[0],enemy_pos[1], enemy_size, enemy_size))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: where do you blit it? You have to blit after `screen.fill(black)` and before `pygame.display.update()`. If you blit it in different place then `screen.fill(black)` will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You blit it in wrong place - you have to do it after `screen.fill(black)` which clears buffer. And before `pygame.display.update()` which sends buffer on screen.

if you blit before `screen.fill(black)` then `fill()` removes it and you can't see it on screen.

```
text = "Score:" + str(enemies_clicked)  
label = font.render(text, 1, red)

screen.fill(black)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (enemy_pos[0],enemy_pos[1], enemy_size, enemy_size))

screen.blit(label, (20, 10))

pygame.display.update()
```